# Dart .onMouseOver

Tags: dart, dart-html

```dart
DivElement collectWoodHover = querySelector("#collectWood");

if (collectWoodHover.onMouseOver == true) {
  querySelector("#collectWoodHover").style.display = "block";
} else {
  querySelector("#collectWoodHover").style.display = "none";
}
```

Hello!

I was flicking through some of the stuff in the auto complete thing in Dart and found `.onMouseOver`.
I wonder if I am using it correctly because it doesn't seem to work.  The `div` element is always hidden.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```dart
collectWoodHover.onMouseOver.listen( (event) {
  print('onMouseOver!');
} );
```

onMouseOver is a stream. You can find more information how to use streams in Dart [here](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/streams/).

Comment: is there any way to get element id in onmousevoer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not selecting the div correctly.

Try:

```dart
querySelector(collectWoodHover).style.display = "block";
```

Because it's a var as in sample, or:

```dart
querySelector("#onHover").style.display = "block";
```

if the div id is 'onHover' that should work

Answer (score 0):

`onMouseOver` is an event stream.
You use it like:

```dart
DivElement collectWoodHover = querySelector("#collectWood");

collectWoodHover.onMouseOver.listen((e) => 
  e.target.style.display = "block";
} 

collectWoodHover.onMouseOut.listen((e) => 
  e.target.style.display = "none";
}
```

I have not actually tried this code. But you should get the idea.